# Routing issues in valorant

Tags: networking

Reason I'm sure it's routing issues is that I talked to riot support, makers of valorant, and after I gave them the ping plotter-results they told me to do a couple of things.

Restart the router then run some commands and disable IPv6, and try DNS. DNS did not work well but the rest yielded amazing results. I played 2 games after this and it was like I was playing a different game. Everything is smooth and I can take gunfights with people without a problem.

After this we are back to normal without me changing anything or restarting the pc or anything.
So. I'm pretty sure it's routing issues.

Also everything is new. Windows is updated. Drivers are updated. No FPS drops or packet loss, router is couple months old, internet speed is 33/6.5 and it seems stable, no overheating...etc And the basics like playing on ethernet and making sure that nothing is taking my speed...etc are covered. Overall nothing I can think of to reflect the problem.

**What is the problem?**

Best I can explain is that I think something happens resulting in my character freezing or 1-2 sort of lagging where I'm just sitting in place. I know for online FPS games there is a hundred things but like I said I ran tests and recorded my gameplay. Right after the fixes I was able to play normally.
But we revert back to the same old sluggish hell that makes me unable to play.

I did this twice as well, counting for placebo because it might be, and same thing. I even tried comparing results with others and it was a stark contrast between the average being 3-5 seconds to die and me dying in 1-2 seconds.

I also noticed that after doing what riot said I had pop ups of higher ping and network issues but things were smooth and I did not have those freezes, I did have higher ping. Those messages continued until my ping settled at a lower number and I did not get the messages and that's when problems were back.

Riot suggested I talk to my ISP but I'd like to know more about the issue and exactly what it is so I can try to explain it. Because you have to understand that where I'm only few have the knowledge and ability to solve my problems. The rest are expected to be braindead. I need to be able to explain it to my ISP like they are 5 all in the hopes that I might get a specialist on the phone.

Even then I should not count on my ISP at all. And obviously I don't want to restart my router, pc, and run commands every 2 games.

Edit: Router is: "ZXHN H168N V3.5" And I don't have money to upgrade it.
Game in question is valorant

Comment: You might want to change your headline (I don't think this is a routing issue, but it may be a router issue - big difference).  You may also want to advise the model of router you have and what games you use (league of legends?).  Can you advise what, if anything you have set up in terms of port forwarding - Looking at https://portforward.com/league-of-legends/ setting up port forwarding or a DMZ on your router may well fix your issues.

Comment: @davidgo, Thanks. I added the game and router. Title is fine. I ruled out everything else. And like I said after doing the things riot said my problem was fixed but only briefly

Comment: Have you set up port forwarding with ports as per  https://www.reddit.com/r/VALORANT/comments/fxeluz/valorant_firewall_port_forwarding/ , or have you set up a DMZ pointing to your computer? [ note the latter is a bit dangerous as it more-or-less exposes your computer directly to the Internet, bypassing the firewall.

Comment: @davidgo, Plz bear with me I'm not good with networking issues.
From my router settings page I'm trying to add it but I run into this issue
https://ibb.co/sycKMY4 the blacked part is my IP. Do I need a particular WAN Host IP address? I tried looking for more online but I'm not getting good results so far

Comment: I am not  familiar with your specific router, but you should not need to specify a WAN IP address - and if your WAN IP is dynamically assigned you can't do that.   It is important that your LAN Host is the internal IP of your computer.